# Python and SQLAlchemy Classical Mapping using autoload: Mapper could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In order to learn more about python I have made the following simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
# -*- Mode: python; c-basic-offset: 4 -*-

from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper

db=create_engine('postgresql://somepassword:someuser@127.0.0.1/hello')
db.echo = False
metadata = MetaData(db)

people=Table('people',metadata,autoload=True)

class People(object):
    pass

people_mapper=mapper(People,people)

db_session=sessionmaker()
db_session.configure(bind=db)

lewis_hamilton=People()
lewis_hamilton.name='Lewis'
lewis_hamilton.surname='Hamilton'
lewis_hamilton.age=44

db_session.save(lewis_hamilton)
db_session.flush()
```

And I use the following table that "Lewis Hamilton" will be inserted (directly from psql):

```
                                 Table "public.people"
 Column  |         Type          |                      Modifiers                      
---------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id      | integer               | not null default nextval('people_id_seq'::regclass)
 name    | character varying(60) | 
 surname | character varying(60) | 
 age     | smallint              |
```

But when I run the script I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|People|people could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'people'

I have also seen the following questions but do not provide the answers I want:

- [SQLAlchemy classical mapper "could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table" despite presence of a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933961/sqlalchemy-classical-mapper-could-not-assemble-any-primary-key-columns-for-mapp)
- [Could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872541/could-not-assemble-any-primary-key-columns-for-mapped-table)
- [SQLAlchemy classical mapper "could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table" despite presence of a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933961/sqlalchemy-classical-mapper-could-not-assemble-any-primary-key-columns-for-mapp)

Because I use autoload in order to load the sql mapping.

Comment: What does \d people output? You have posted the columns but not indices displayed after these.  Could you maybe modify your post to include this part as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- About database URI format: user name goes before user password, so it should be `'postgresql://someuser:somepassword@127.0.0.1/hello'` in your example.
- We can pass [`echo`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo) flag in `create_engine`: it is better than setting attribute, moreover it is set to `False` by default, so we don't need it at all in particular case.
- If you don't want to write your [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object schema with [`Column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) objects (more info at [Describing Databases with MetaData](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#metadata-describing)) – just [reflect your `metadata`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect) and obtain `'people'` table from [`tables` field](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.tables) of `metadata` object.
- [`sessionmaker`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker) is [`Session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) objects [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), not `Session` object, so you should use double call (looks ugly) or extract `sessionmaker` instance as separate object (in our case we will call it `session_factory`).
- AFAIK `Session` objects doesn't have method `save`, but [`add`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add).
- If we want our changes (adding `lewis_hamilton` record to table) to be saved we should call [`commit`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit) method in the end since [`flush`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) communicates with database but without committing changes record will be lost (in your case we can work without `flush` method calls, you can read more about `flush` vs `commit` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201455/sqlalchemy-whats-the-difference-between-flush-and-commit)).

With all these comments something like this should work

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper

db = create_engine('postgresql://someuser:somepassword@127.0.0.1/hello')
metadata = MetaData(db)

# reflecting 'people' table from database schema
metadata.reflect(only=['people'])
people = metadata.tables['people']


class People(object):
    pass


people_mapper = mapper(People, people)

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=db)
db_session = session_factory()

lewis_hamilton = People()
lewis_hamilton.name = 'Lewis'
lewis_hamilton.surname = 'Hamilton'
lewis_hamilton.age = 44

db_session.add(lewis_hamilton)
db_session.commit()
```

but it will be better (since it is more explicit, [second principle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python)) to create `people` `Table` object using `Column` objects instead of reflecting like

```
people = Table('people', metadata,
               Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
               Column('name', String(60)),
               Column('surname', String(60)),
               Column('age', SmallInteger))
```

Also if you want to map class `People` with `'people'` table following [Object Relational Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#object-relational-tutorial) we will have something like

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

db = create_engine('postgresql://someuser:somepassword@127.0.0.1/hello')
metadata = MetaData(db)
people = Table('people', metadata,
               Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
               Column('name', String(60)),
               Column('surname', String(60)),
               Column('age', SmallInteger))

Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class People(Base):
    __table__ = people
```

or without `people` `Table` object:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

db = create_engine('postgresql://someuser:somepassword@127.0.0.1/hello')

metadata = MetaData(db)
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class People(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(60))
    surname = Column('surname', String(60))
    age = Column('age', SmallInteger)
```

and we can add [`__init__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) as well so finally we will have

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

db = create_engine('postgresql://someuser:somepassword@127.0.0.1/hello')

metadata = MetaData(db)
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class People(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(60))
    surname = Column('surname', String(60))
    age = Column('age', SmallInteger)

    def __init__(self, name, surname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age


session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=db)
db_session = session_factory()

lewis_hamilton = People(name='Lewis',
                        surname='Hamilton',
                        age=44)

db_session.add(lewis_hamilton)
db_session.commit()
```

---

## Further improvements

As said in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Wildcard imports ( from  import * ) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be overwritten isn't known in advance).

so your line

```
from sqlalchemy import *
```

should be more specific since there are a lot of things inside and you don't need them all.

Comment: In the end by mapping my table into a class works (last example) the others did not work form me.

Comment: what exactly happens?